# changing DataTable's DataRow style in flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I want each DataRow of DataTable to have a Card look this this:
[our DataRow custom design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86l2O.png)

I looked at the source code but I could not find anything